# How to paint road texture over Terrain at runtime in Unity 2019

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am planning on making a city building game in the vein of SimCity 2000 and Zeus in Unity. While looking at Unity's Terrain component and its experimental terrain API, I was under the impression that it would be trivial to paint texture over Terrain at runtime considering it is easily done in Editor, but it turns out it's not.

What's the approach to painting road or any texture over Terrain at runtime? Can it be achieved using Unity's Terrain and its API? How did these old games implement this?

I am aware of assets in the Unity Asset Store which can be used to achieve this, but I am looking to learn the underlying concept.

Comment: Is it expected that action be done by the user or by a script in runtime?

Comment: yes by the user, at run-time.